# Django crontab not executing test function

Tags: python, django

I have following:

1. ```
      python manage.py crontab show # this command give following

      Currently active jobs in crontab:
      12151a7f59f3f0be816fa30b31e7cc4d -> ('*/1 * * * *', 'media_api_server.cron.cronSendEmail')
   ```
2. My app is in virtual environment (env) active
3. In my `media_api_server/cron.py` I have following function:

   ```
    def cronSendEmail():
        print("Hello")
        return true
   ```
4. In `settings.py` module:

   ```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        ......
        'django_crontab',
    )

    CRONJOBS = [
        ('*/1 * * * *', 'media_api_server.cron.cronSendEmail')
    ]
   ```

To me all defined in place but when I run `python manage.py runserver` in virtual environment, console doesn't print anything.

```
    System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
    July 26, 2016 - 12:12:52
    Django version 1.8.1, using settings 'mediaserver.settings'
    Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

'Django-crontab' module is not working. I followed it's documentation from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-crontab

Comment: `django-crontab` is a package to manage the user's crontab via django commands, it doesn't schedule commands itself. Did you run `manage.py crontab add` and check your user's crontab (via `crontab -l`)? Does your system even run cron? If so, are there any errors in cron's logfile?

Comment: crontab -l says: */1 * * * * /var/www/html/projects/mediaserver/env/bin/python2.7 /var/www/html/projects/mediaserver/media/manage.py crontab run 12151a7f59f3f0be816fa30b31e7cc4d # django-cronjobs for mediaserver

and 'sudo service cron start' says: 
start: Job is already running: cron

Comment: So django-crontab did it's job. Check `/var/log/cron` (if that still exists on your system, otherwise you might need to ask journald). Did you get any mails from cron informing you that something went wrong?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your code actually works. You may be think that `print("Hello")` should appear in stdout? So it doesn't work that way, because cron doesn't use `stdour` and `stderr` for it's output. To see actual results you should point path to some log file in `CRONJOBS` list: just put `'>> /path/to/log/file.log'` as last argument, e.g:

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/1 * * * *', 'media_api_server.cron.cronSendEmail', '>> /path/to/log/file.log')
]
```

Also it might be helpful to redirect your errors to stdout too. For this you heed to add `CRONTAB_COMMAND_SUFFIX = '2>&1'` to your `settings.py`

Comment: If you are adding an output redirection, make sure that all the folders exsits, if not the cron will fail.

Answer (score 2):

@swapnil-pingle's answer worked for me in macOS Monterey as well.
Mentioning steps here from the [link](https://dccxi.com/posts/crontab-not-working-catalina/).

1.

```
Mac -> System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access
```

2. 

press `+`.

3.

select `/usr/sbin/cron` location.

At last started my server again. and it worked.

**Note:**

-print() is not working in cron file.

-to check if cron is working, I updated data in DB obj.

Answer (score 1):

`source` sometimes not working in shell scripts

use `.` (dot) instead

```
*/1 * * * * . /home/app/env/bin/activate e.t.c.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the crontab with a first line like:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

Create the new line at crontab with:

```
./manage.py crontab add
```

And change the line created by crontab library with the command:

> crontab -e

```
*/1 * * * * source /home/app/env/bin/activate && /home/app/manage.py crontab run 123HASHOFTASK123
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way, directly in the OS( in case you are running on a Unix system), so that you won't have to fiddle with python libraries. Provided your OS user has all permissions/owns the django project, you can do it on the command line and in the directory where your project folder is;

```
user@server:~$ crontab -l
0 6 * * * python PROJECT/manage.py shell -c "<--import statements; function calls;-->"
```

Just sharing, cause recently I've had similar such situation and this turned out be a clean workaround