# django-crontab does not execute scheduled jobs

Tags: python, django, cron

I am having a very similar virtualenv setup than in the question:
[Django crontab not executing test function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589830/django-crontab-not-executing-test-function).

in **my_app.cron.py**

```
 def test():
        print('HELLO')
```

in **settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_crontab',
)
CRONTAB_COMMAND_SUFFIX = '2>&1'
CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/1 * * * *', 'my_app.cron.test','>> /cron_job.log'),
]
```

***`python manage.py crontab add`***

```
adding cronjob: (bee8ad945bb9c6b15a3ff0847481a181) -> ('*/1 * * * *', 'my_app.cron.test', '>> /cron_job.log')
```

***`python manage.py crontab show`***

```
Currently active jobs in crontab:
bee8ad945bb9c6b15a3ff0847481a181 -> ('*/1 * * * *', 'my_app.cron.test', '>> /cron_job.log')
```

Everything seems fine yet nothing is printed in the log file or the console. What's missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not have permissions to write to the root of your filesystem. Try moving `/cron_job.log` to `/var/log/django_cron_job.log` or `~/cron_job.log`